In postgresql, can a foreign key constraint be modified to allow additional values beyond those in the referenced column?
Let's say I have a pending_order table with a user_id column which references the id column of a users table.
In a different table, let's call it forecast, I realised I had some use cases / scenarios where it was useful to have the concept of the "the system" being the user, with an arbitrary user_id (eg -99). So since the forecast table did not have referential integrity, it was easy to add records where the user_id was -99.
Now, I am realising I also need similar behavior in the pending_order table but this table does have referential integrity; it already has a proper foreign key column user_id as mentioned earlier.
question 1
Regardless of whether it's a good idea to do or not, is it possible to expand the constraint automatically created by postgres for the user_id column, to include the value -99 even though it's not a valid user id?
question 2
Do ppl do this, or is it like a really bad idea? I can't tell; would appreciate some insight from experienced devs/dbas. If it's a bad idea I'm thinking of just removing the foreign key constraint entirely from pending_order as this isn't a super critical table that needs to have perfect referential integrity?

Just create 'dummy' user with id of -99 and name of system.

@AdrianKlaver I thought of that, but it would complicate a lot of UX logic all over the place where we wouldn't want to expose this "system user". But, yeah - it may well come to that. I just want to invade the minimum amount of code as possible, hence this question.

Why would that be complicated? You can use this default -99 as a default.

@FrankHeikens - no, i don't mean the sql / relational model would be complicated with a new user with id -99. I'm talking about changing business logic in the larger application codebase, which I would like to avoid (or at least defer)

@yen You might be able to avoid (larger) changes to the application - at the expense of more complex database - by creating views or RLS policies that hide the "system user" row from normal queries

I would keep the foreign key constraint, but make the column nullable. If it's null, it doesn't need to reference any row in the referenced table.
